# Symfony: trying to overwriting a method of a symfony class

Tags: symfony1

i want to overwrite a method of
*symfony/lib/plugins/sfDoctrinePlugin/lib/form/sfFormDoctrine.class.php.*

I think a good way could be writing again the method in the form class
where i need that method.

In that case if i need that method in other form class should i write
again the new method, so i would break the rule DRY...

So is there any better way?

Regards

Javi

Answer (score 4):

You should be using `BaseFormDoctrine` if this is a Doctrine specific method or `BaseForm` if you want the method to apply to all forms. These form classes are provided specifically for this purpose.

Comment: just to speed up from finding the classes, BaseFormDoctrine is situated in /lib/form/doctrine/BaseFormDoctrine.class.php and BaseForm is in /lib/form/BaseFormDoctrine.class.php

Answer (score 2):

Piggybacking on Colonel Sponz's answer, I've done this many times by extending the class I want to override. By extending the class, you don't have to duplicate anything. In the method(s) you want to customize, just add your customized code and then call `parent::method_name()` to execute the same method of the super class. You get all the benefits of both. Calls to methods that don't exist in the subclass will execute against the super class.

It should be noted that this strategy is basic OOP stuff and isn't limited to Symfony or even PHP.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new class that inherits from `sfFormDoctrine` that redeclares the methods you need and then use your new class in place of `sfFormDoctrine` wherever you need that method.